# Database Role membership Db_owner and db_ddladmin in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

A user got a database membership `db_owner`. Is there any need to give additional
role `db_ddladmin` as an extra role. **OR,** the `db_owner` itself can able to do what ever action done by the `db_ddladmin`?

When edit one of the users (under security folder in ssms), it shows that the user is a member of `db_owner`, `db_datawriter` and `db_ddladmin`.

If `db_owner` can do all the action then what is the need of checking any other role member like `db_datareader`, `db_ddladmin` etc

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link that will help define all the fixed roles.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx

To answer your question db_owner supercedes db_ddladmin, so db_owner is the only role you would need.

Comment: thanks for this.But i can see most of the time the db_owner and db_ddladmin have been checked!!!

Comment: That could be because someone isn't exactly sure what db_ddladmin does and is "being safe" by checking it.